# Why enable_shared_from_this must be publicly inherited?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I just had an hard time understanding why this code was throwing.
All the other solutions on SO said you need to have a shared_ptr instance in order to use shared_from_this(), and I had it!
But nonetheless, the code was still crashing like all the other questions were describing.

Here is a simplified version of the code

main.cpp

```
uint16_t port = 9876;
auto inout = cms::MultiTcpInOut::create(port);
inout->start_accept();
```

MultiTcpInOut.h

```
#ifndef MULTITCPINOUT_H
#define MULTITCPINOUT_H

#include <memory>
#include <utility>

namespace cms {

    using namespace std;

    class MultiTcpInOut : private enable_shared_from_this<MultiTcpInOut>
    {
        public:
            static shared_ptr<MultiTcpInOut> create(uint16_t port)
            {
                return shared_ptr<MultiTcpInOut>(new MultiTcpInOut(port));
            }

            virtual ~MultiTcpInOut();

            // start_accept() can not be called from the constructor because it uses shared_from_this(), and
            // make_shared<>() haven't finished yet when it is called. Let the instantiating code call it
            void start_accept();

        protected:
            MultiTcpInOut(uint16_t port);
    };
}
#endif // MULTITCPINOUT_H
```

MultiTcpInOut.cpp

```
void MultiTcpInOut::start_accept()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Starting accept";
    auto socket = make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
    auto shrd_this = shared_from_this();
    acceptor->async_accept(*socket.get(), bind(&MultiTcpInOut::handle_accept, shrd_this, socket, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

---

Changing the `private enable_shared_from_this<MultiTcpInOut>` to `public enable_shared_from_this<MultiTcpInOut>` fixed the problem.

Nowhere it says it must be inherited publicly ([at least reading the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)), and I don't understand why it has not, since I was calling it from a class method!

So, why does it have to be public?
Is it so clear that it's not mentioned in the spec?

To help someone which might have my same problem

### ***ENABLE_SHARED_FROM_THIS MUST BE INHERITED AS PUBLIC!!!***

Comment: It's indeed a duplicate. I couldn't find that question when searching on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from cppreference: 'A common (until C++17)standard (since C++17) implementation for enable_shared_from_this is to hold a weak reference (such as std::weak_ptr) to this. The constructors of std::shared_ptr detect the presence of an enable_shared_from_this base and assign the newly created std::shared_ptr to the internally stored weak reference.' That is, `std::shared_ptr<>` needs write access to this field, not just your class.

Comment: Someone needs to read how the library is implemented and infer that it's needed to be public.. Not the clearest of the approaches.
Moreover it's just a 'common' way, not the only way

Comment: @Makers_F : From C++17, it's the only way. Also, how would you do this differently in O(1), i.e., without global `std::map<>` lookup? `enable_shared_from_this` is indeed intrusive, which means you might as well use reference-counted ptrs...

Comment: The question is marked C++11. I'm sure an experienced developer would not make the same mistake I made and could easily infer what you explained. But why, if the only way to use it is to make it public, that's not stated explicitly in the documentation or enforced at compile time (is that even possible? I'm still studying templates)

Comment: @Makers_F: In general it's impossible, but for CRTP (i.e., when you pass the descendant as a template parameter) you might just verify if `(Base*)(Descendant*)nullptr` is valid or something... I also can't see why this verification is not done. You might bring it up to WG21...